# JavaFX application iterative function

Tags: javafx

I am designing a JavaFX application and I would like my system to check whether a `MediaPlayer` object is `STATUS.Playing()` at every "iteration" of my application. So, I don't want it to check once, I want it to be checked at every "tick" of the application's clock. Where could I do this check? Is there a function that is called iteratively while my application is running?

So far, I have been able to do what I want by adding a `TimeLine` object that iterates every n milliseconds, but I wonder whether there is a cleaner way to do it.

Cheers

Comment: Checkout the AnimationTimer.

Comment: Please explain `iteration of my application.` If you just want to keep a note of the change in the status of the MediaPlayer use the [`statusProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#statusProperty--).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It seems you would be able to get exactly the same effect by registering a change listener with the statusProperty(), as @ItachiUchiha implies, with less complex code and better performance than using the method you suggest.

Comment: I understand what @ItachiUchiha is saying, but I want to detect whether the status == PLAYING every 20 milliseconds (for example). Not just once.

Comment: To give you a better example, a video game's code might contain a render() function which is called every time a frame is displayed. Is there something similar in a JavaFX application?

Comment: Have a look at [AnimationTimer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) as suggested by @UlukBiy

Comment: Yes, AnimationTimer is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!